# Stop conversion decimal to ascii

Tags: java, android, arduino, ascii, inputstream

I am trying to send an int from arduino to android via bluetooth but if i send lets say 56, i receive 8 in the android side...is there anyway i can receive 56 as it is and preferably in string form including characters

Arduino code :

```
int level = 56;
Serial.write(level);
```

Android code :

```
 public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
        int bytes;


        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
                String strReceived = new String(buffer, 0,bytes);
                final String msgReceived =/* String.valueOf(bytes) +
                        " bytes received: "
                        + */strReceived;



                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      textStatus.setText(msgReceived);
                        value = msgReceived ;
                    }});
```

Value is defined as a static string as a class variable

Comment: Your code is converting the bytes into a string. If you don't want to do that, don't... it's not clear why you're calling the string constructor if you don't want to convert the received bytes into text.

Comment: i will need characters in a future stage in app so thats why i would have preffered it

Comment: Warning: [new String(byte[], int, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-int-int-) uses the platform's default character set and encoding. Instead, you should explicitly use the same on both systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're converting the bytes to string and therefore you're getting `'8'` which is `(char)56;`. If you don't want that, simply do as follows.

```
bytes = connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
String tmp = "";
for(int i=0;i<bytes;i++)
    tmp += Byte.toString(buffer[i]);  
final String msgReceived = tmp;
```

**EDIT**

If you send as follows, for example.

```
Serial.write(56);
Serial.write(76);
```

What you will receive in `msgReceived` will be `5676` if both these bytes are read. You can obviously change this behavior in whichever way you want.

Comment: can u edit with the a loop example...?// also i cannot access the variable from the run function

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with received bytes. Wait, I'll edit the code and mention the output it will give.

Comment: i am receiving 56565656565656565565.. and so on i know i can limit buffer to just 1 but the range of 1 byte is 0 to 255,but i  m repeatedly sending values from arduino from 0 to 3000,so is there anyway to receive it from 1 to 3000 and clear it all on next received.

Comment: You cant try [`ByteBuffer.getInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getInt())

Comment: can you post a example or plz elaborate it

Comment: @PuneetSharma First can you just show what output you're getting when you send `3000` using your original code in the question.\

Comment: when i keep buffer size 128 i get 3000300030003000030003000300030030.. and if i keep buffer size 2 i get 300 or 0030 or 0003...and do add i m receveing continously

Comment: well i used tom blodget advice and it worked but your's helped too thx